# How the Node.js async eachLimit works in this situation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

I wrote a little [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) script to batch insert a lot of JSON files into a MongoDB sharded cluster. This is my first time with this module (and I'm still learning Node.js). I don't know if I'm doing it right.

- The code is the last part of a waterfall (1): previous functions end
  up with an object with `db`, `coll` and `files` properties.
- `files` array contains hundred of file paths and the function to
  apply to each element of the array is, again, a waterfall (2).
- Waterfall (2) is made of the following: read, parse, insert. When this waterfall ends (3) I call `complete` to finalize the processing of a single item in the array, passing the error (if any).

So far so good, correct?

What I can't understand is what happens inside the `async.eachLimit` callback (4). From the documentation:

> A callback which is called after all the iterator functions have
>   finished, or an error has occurred.

That is, when all functions have finished, the `next()` call (5) ends the script.  But the same callback (4) is invoked when a single error occurred, as per documentation. That is my script stops when a fail with a single file happens.

How can I avoid this?

```
async.waterfall([ // 1
    // ...
    function (obj, next) {
        async.eachLimit(obj.files, 1000,
            function (file, complete) {
                async.waterfall([ // 2
                    function (next) {
                        fs.readFile(file, {}, function (err, data) {
                            next(err, data);
                        });
                    },
                    function (data, next) { // Parse (assuming all well formed)
                        next(null, JSON.parse(data));
                    },
                    function (doc, next) { // Insert
                        obj.coll.insert(doc, {w: 1}, function (err, doc) {
                            next(err);
                        });
                    }
                ], function (err, result) { // 3
                    complete(err);
                });
            },
            function (err) { // 4
                if (err) console.error(err);
                next(null, obj); // 5
            }
        );
    }
], function (err, obj) { // Waterfall end
    if (err) console.error(err);
    obj.db.close(); // Always close the connection
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want it to break in case of an error you should just invoke the callback with a falsy first parameter, like so (look after // 3).
Is this ok with you / did I understand correctly?

```
async.waterfall([ // 1
    // ...
    function (obj, next) {
        async.eachLimit(obj.files, 1000,
            function (file, complete) {
                async.waterfall([ // 2
                    function (next) {
                        fs.readFile(file, {}, function (err, data) {
                            next(err, data);
                        });
                    },
                    function (data, next) { // Parse (assuming all well formed)
                        next(null, JSON.parse(data));
                    },
                    function (doc, next) { // Insert
                        obj.coll.insert(doc, {w: 1}, function (err, doc) {
                            next(err);
                        });
                    }
                ], function (err, result) { // 3
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(file + ' threw an error');
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log('proceeding with execution');
                    }
                    complete();
                });
            },
            function (err) { // 4
                next(null, obj); // 5
            }
        );
    }
], function (err, obj) { // Waterfall end
    if (err) console.error(err);
    obj.db.close(); // Always close the connection
});
```

Comment: Looks legit, but it doesn't work. Callback 4 is executed and the script exits as soon as the first error occurs. Am I'm missing something?

Comment: So you are calling `complete` without parameters?

Comment: Works, sorry it was my mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Ehehe grazie ciao! Mind if I ask you a little help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445649/why-async-map-function-works-with-the-native-fs-stat-function

Comment: All the callbacks are missing return statements.

Comment: Why should you return in this case?