# Why async.map function works with the native fs.stat function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results){
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});
```

As per [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback), the second argument is:

> iterator(item, callback) - A function to apply to each item in the
>   array.

Fine.

> The iterator is passed a callback(err, transformed) which must
>   be called once it has completed with an error (which can be null) and
>   a transformed item.

I think that`fs.stat` does not conform to this and  I would say that this shouldn't work.

It should be something like:

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'],
    function (file, complete) {
        fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
            complete(err, stat)
        });
    }, function(err, results){
        // results is now an array of stats for each file
    }
);
```

Comment: "Afaik fs.stat dos not call `callback(err, stat)`" What do you mean by that? That's exactly what you're doing in your code.

Comment: @SLaks I mean why passing fs.stat works with async.map. My example is how I would implement the same behavior.

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense.  Your code does exactly what you claim doesn't work.

Comment: He's asking why the first example works. In the second he wrote how he would have coded it (because he's confused about why the first works).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fs.stat` accepts two parameters, the first is the file, the second is the callback, which by node convention accepts two parameters, an error and the stats of the file:

```
fs.stat(path, callback)
```

which could be seen as

```
fs.stat(path, function(err, stats){
  // ...
});
```

This is why it works, `fs.stat` is called by passing exactly what it needs.

More info: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

## fs.stat(path, callback)

Asynchronous stat(2). The callback gets two arguments (err, stats) where stats is a fs.Stats object. See the fs.Stats section below for more information.

Since the fs.stat callback returns (err, stats), the following works fine

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results){
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});
```

To do the same yourself pass a function which with the appropriate callback

```
var async = require('async')
var inspect = require('eyespect').inspector();
function custom(param, callback) {
  var result = 'foo result'
  var err = null
  callback(err, result)
}

var items = ['item1', 'item2']
async.map(items, custom, function (err, results) {
  inspect(results, 'results')
})
```